# Hide password through html

Tags: html, css, hover, visibility

I am trying to make the passwords not visible when a user is not directly hovering over the password. When they do hover the text should appear. My current code is this below, but I can not get the hover to correctly work. It either disappears completely or stays put.

```
<style>
#pass.a{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#pass.a:hover{
    visibility:visible;
    }
</style>
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="pass"><a> Password </a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Why does this not work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, you have a bug:

```
#pass a{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#pass a:hover{
    visibility:visible;
    }
```

However there is still another mistake. Once the element disappears, the hover won't trigger. You want the sibling selector:

```
#pass:hover > a
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/IzEBeQuw/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

`#pass.a{` is looking for an element with `id="pass" class="a"`

You want

`#pass a {` and
`#pass a:hover` { to select the `a` that is a child of the element with `id="pass"`

Answer (score 0):

`#pass.a` means *element with id=pass and class=a*. I don't think it's what you're looking for.

Replace dot with space:

```
#pass a
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

#pass a:hover
{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you use `.` selector. Which usually represents a class selector. And in your case you need to select element through tag selector `#pass a`.

Try:

```
#pass a{
    visibility:hidden;
}

#pass a:hover{
   visibility:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine.

## pass a{visibility:hidden;}

## pass:hover>a{visibility:visible;}